How to tell the difference between adult male Golden Orb spider and a juvenile female of the same size?
I believe these are Golden Orb-weavers (Nephila pilipes). PHotos of large adult females can be found in Do these large spiders in Taiwan belong to different species? They are quite common in Taiwan (and a wide swath of countires).
Based on photos around the internet, especially inaturalist.org and Wikimedia commons the little red one seems to be more likely an adult male rather than a juvenile female.
But I don't know!
This female is about 20 mm; I don't think I've ever seen one below 15 mm in a web at eye level. It's not uncommon to see them at 50 mm long (just the body).
It's hard to estimate the size of the little red one because it was in a parallel web about 10 cm behind the female's, and the mosquitos were going crazy on my arms and legs so I didn't spent time to get them both in focus at the same time for comparison.
Question: But I'm curious, what DO juvenile female Golden Orb-weaving spiders look like when they are growing up? Are they always distinguishable from males of equivalent size when growing up?

I've used my brave extraterestrial friend "LOCK Jian" (LOCK小將) (1, 2) for scale:




Update!
Looking through photos from a few weeks ago (same hiking trail) I found another pair. This female was slightly bigger (maybe 25 mm) but the little red companion this time was in the same web.
What's notable is that this little red spider is all round and plump, not elongated and rectangular like the one in the first set of photos! I esitmate that it was a bit smaller, maybe 3-4 mm.


